# How to yank a socket from under another thread in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, sockets, thread-safety

I am writing a simple multithreaded chat server in Python3. Sometimes i want to interrupt another thread that is waiting in [socket.recv()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv) to allow the theread to perform cleanup tasks.

Is calling [socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/socket.html#socket.socket.shutdown) from another thread safe?

Comment: You may want to look into [select()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html) You can then listen to multiple inputs and choose whichever is ready to provide you with data.

Comment: @TemporalWolf I know about selectors. Unfortunately, this is a homework assignment, and we must use multithreaded raw sockets.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27790293/1005379) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8050401/1005379) seems to indicate that this is in fact the recommended way, but i'm not sure how it works in a high-level language such as Python

Comment: I'd encourage you to review [how to ask homework questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Show us what you've done/tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `socket.shutdown` from another thread is reasonably safe, and, as @kinokikuf mentioned, is an appropriate way to terminate a blocking `recv()` in another thread, as long as you can guarantee that the socket is not yet closed when the call to `shutdown()` happens.

If you cannot guarantee that the socket isn't yet closed, you may get an exception when calling shutdown or you might even terminate another unrelated connection if a race-condition happens and the socket handle is reused by the OS!

The [Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/shutdown) for the `shutdown()` system call doesn't explicitly state that blocking recv() calls will be terminated, only that "further receptions and transmissions will be disallowed". But in practice this seems to include blocking `recv()` calls on the same socket on both Unixoid systems and Windows.

Another way would be to use [socket.settimeout()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout) to circumvent the indefinite blocking problem and regularly check (e.g. with global variables) inside the thread if the connection should be closed.

Yet another reasonable way to interrupt the `recv()` would be to send a non-lethal signal to the thread, which will interrupt the recv() system call, but there seems to be no wrapper for the low-level `pthread_kill` function in Python and since Python 3.5 [system calls will be automatically restarted if interrupted](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-475-retry-system-calls-failing-with-eintr), which makes this option unusable.

Comment: Thanks! I'm only calling close() from the thread that manages the function, so i'm always shutting down a open socket.